# CoCreateInstance exception. Class registration using REGSVR32 on a static library?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, com, static-libraries

The code(a snippet from my c++ com server project built for Win32 platform, in my c# app):

```
CComPtr<IMSPRProvider> test;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MSPRProvider, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMSPRProvider, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&test));
```

The HR: regdb_e_classnotreg. class not registered

In this same project I have an older WMDRM drm implementation that works just fine with cocreateinstance calls. So the issue is particular to the new playready classes.

I see other questions with this exception that suggest registering the dll using regsvr32.exe. If that is the solution, I have two questions:

1. I never needed to register anything else(like the WMDRM stuff) so why this?
2. I'm using the PlayReady SDK which consists of some .h, .idl, and .lib files that I've linked into my project. I do not have a dynamic library. What is the equivalent solution for static libraries?

PS: I have almost zero experience with c++. I am seriously winging all of this so my apologies if I haven't given sufficient details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CoCreateInstance` creates an instance using server which somehow needs to be available. In most cases the server is a DLL and it needs to be registered with regsvr32 first so that CLSID in question is written in global list and API knows how where to look for implementation.

> I never needed to register anything else(like the WMDRM stuff) so why this?

`REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` indicates that server is not registered, so you need to do it. If you never did it before then you have it done for you by something else.

> I'm using the PlayReady SDK which consists of some .h, .idl, and .lib files that I've linked into my project. I do not have a dynamic library. What is the equivalent solution for static libraries?

There is no equivalent for static library. `CoCreateInstance` creates an instance using standard API. You just don't need it for static library at all if implementation is linked in. Most likely, however, your "static library" is only a front end and/or declaration and the real implementation is in dynamic load library. Hence `CoCreateInstance`, and the registration.

Another thing for you to note is 32/64-bit confusion. Your code should be matching bitness of the DLL. In case of mismatch you can again run into `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` problem.

Comment: So it is not registration of the playready(or wmdrm) stuff but rather my com server project itself. I'll look into that; if it works, I'll resolve this question. Thanks very much.

Comment: If the quoted code line results in this error, then it's about registration of COM server (presumably, DLL) which implements `CLSID_MSPRProvider` class.

Comment: I got it. The ATL wizard added its own .rgs com registrar script for my class rather than appending the new class to the main .rgs. Thats why it works for the other previous classes for that project and thats why I never had to manually do anything with regsvr32. By manually editing the scripts, I got the new class to register and the CoCreateInstance works. Thanks very much for starting me out in the right direction. The solution was really a matter of visual studio config file management.